# how to install Eclipse neon via the software manager

Tags: eclipse

I cant find Eclipse neon in the software manager. There are some very lengthy tutorials on how to do it via the terminal using some yedi tricks. I cant do that, I use Eclipse for work and not as a play station substitution, I need to install it and run it and get my work done. I come from windows, there I just hit the setup.exe and Im done. So I need a similar way in Linux which must exist because I read that all applications can be installed via the software manager which led me to now switch to Linux. Thanks for any hints.

PS: Thanks for the warm welcome by giving a down vote 15 minutes after posting. Really encouraging the Linux newbies ...

Comment: what does it mean by yedi in this post?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ .  Find the "Get Eclipse Neon" block, there should be a "Download 64 bit" button there, then the "Download" button.  That will give you a "eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz".  Open it with your archive manager.  Extract it to a temporary location (subdir of Downloads, most likely).  Then open the resulting "eclipse-installer" directory and execute the "eclipse-inst" executable.  Follow the instructions.

In short, the packaged software installer for Linux will be a little behind the latest available versions for packages, and may not always be the best way to install particular things.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need a particular eclipse like the php edition? I can see only the general edition.

Comment: Then click on "Download Packages" instead of "Download 64 Bit".

Comment: I tried that already but the php edition I get with that does not contain an inst folder so I cannot install it.

Comment: The "packages" installer just contains the Eclipse installation, not the installer.  Extract it to a permanent location in your home dir somewhere. Set up a launcher to execute the "eclipse/eclipse" application, and that will run Eclipse.